# What Haxe game engine do you prefer?

Tags: programming, game-development

So I've been looking into Haxe recently as an option for game development. (In fact, I've been trying everything for game development recently. Kivy, Pygame, AGK BASIC/C++, Java, etc...) I'm best with Gamemaker, so when I go into an engine like Pygame or AGK, I set up a Gamemaker-like framework for the game with arrays of objects and such for easy game management.

So what would you recommend I use? I was thinking OpenFL simply because it has a lot of great games made in it. But then I looked at HaxeFlixel which looks great on the surface, but I'm not a big fan of how the game is made. HaxePunk might be alright, but I'm just checking stuff out from the main Haxe site.

I'd like to be able to port to Windows, Mac, Linux, Android iOS, and HTML5, as well. But other than that, I'm no Haxe expert, so I don't know what would be best for 2D game development.

Do any long-time Haxe users have a preferred engine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Starting to use HaxFlixel. Did you settle on one yet?